# paging through a very large text file

Tags: java, text, paging

I need to implement a paging widget that would be able to read an arbitrarily large text file. widget will be used by different apps with a wide range of hardware (mobile with low ram on low end) so need to be fairly memory stingy and efficient. the amount to be paged is also going to be arbitrarily different for each user. is there any free sample code that has implemented this somewhere? i'm looking for a java snippet really if possible.

Answer (score 4):

java.io.RandomAccessFile should be helpful here, as it allows you start reading anywhere in the file. This enables you to only keep the current page in memory.